# NullReferenceException in Unity despite added script as a component

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, nullreferenceexception

My code throws an error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

public class scoreScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    /* the text object we want to edit the text of (there are two different types of text in unity so it needs to be specified */
    UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreText;
    public static int chocAmount; //amount of chocolate eaten


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // UnityEngine.UI.Text scoreText = (UnityEngine.UI.Text)gameObject.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();
        scoreText = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = "x " + chocAmount.ToString();
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown for **line 26**:

```cs
scoreText.text = "x " + chocAmount.ToString();
```

And yes, I did add the script to a Text-UI-Object:

**Components of UI gameobject**
[image: Components of UI gameobject]

Comment: Tested your code with attached script and text component - it works, no exceptions. Any chance your script is attached to the wrong game object, e.g. to the parent game object of the text? GetComponent only searches for components in the object, the script is attached to, children excluded. Maybe you need to use GetComponentInChildren, or navigate your transform hierarchy by code.

Comment: I haven't messed with Unity in awhile, but shouldn't your scoreText object be a reference to a TextMeshPro, and not a regular Text? Based on what I'm seeing in your screenshot, scoreText = GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Text>();  is returning null as you've attached a TextMeshPro, not a Text.

Comment: @Alex Good idea, unfortunately it doesn't work either (or at least isn't the only issue), throws the same Exception at the same line :/

Comment: @bartol44 no, it is definitely attached to the Text and not the canvas.

Comment: The textmesh pro text is not a ui.text. So it is simply saying I did not find it. And it would be right.

Comment: @Alex  Okay nice so it for some reason didn't work as a TextMeshPro but I've now used the old Legacy Text gameObject and reverted to the old code and that works now, ty :)

Comment: The reason is, despite the name, entirely different types, get component text won't just grab text mesh pro text

Answer (score 2):

If you have attached `TextMeshPro-Text` component to a `gameobject` you have to get the same via script,
Here the component you are getting in script mismatches with the component you have attached.

Answer (score 1):

```
UnityEngine.UI.Text
```

is simply the wrong type.

What you want / have attached to your object is a

```
TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI
```

or the more generic

```
TMPro.TMP_Text
```